# How should I fix my code to read all the rows in the CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, analysis

```
import csv
import ujson
from konlpy.tag import Okt

def ss(line):
    
    line = line.strip().replace(". ", ".\n")
    line = line.splitlines()
    return line 

def anal(analyzer, sent):
    tp =[]
    for i in sent:
        text = analyzer.pos(i)
        text_pos.append(text)
        
    return tp

input_file_name = r"data.csv"

with open(input_file_name, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as input_file:
    okt=Okt()
    
    for line in input_file:   
        sent = split_sentences(line)
        text_pos = get_pos(okt, sentence)

output_file_name=r"data1.json"
    
with open(output_file_name, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
    for get_pos in text_pos:
        text_str = ujson.dumps(text_pos, ensure_ascii=False)
        print(text_str, file=output_file)
```

This is what I have so far, but only the last row of the CSV file is being read and analyzed. I want to fix my code to read all the rows of the CSV file (it has 5276 rows in total) and do the analysis. What should I try?

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do but if you want to read CSV then use module `csv` or `pandas`. And later try to works with data. Don't try to parse CSV on your own because it can be more complex problem that you think.

Comment: if you have incorrectly formatted file CSV then show what you have in this file. We can't read in your mind and we can't know what is your problem.

Comment: standard rule: if you have many values then keep them on list. But you keep only last value in `text_pos`. You need `text_pos = []` before loop, and `text_pos.append( get_pos(...) )` inside loop.

Comment: Can you give a small example (but big enough to show the problem) of **exactly** what is in your file, and **exactly** what the program should output as a result?

Answer (score 1):

In the following loop you are overwriting sentence and text_pos each iteration of the loop.

```py
    for line in input_file:   
        sentence = split_sentences(line)
        text_pos = get_pos(okt, sentence)
```

In the last iteration of the loop text_pos and sentence will be from the last line. If I were you I would try creating a list before the loop and appending the result of get_pos to the list. Later on you can write each result to your output file.

Disclaimer: I don't have experience with the Okt library. Hopefully my hunch is correct.